# Hunting the UNIX software configure Uber-script

Tags: unix, installation

I have been installing alot of Linux software lately.  Installing almost always requires running a "configure" script.  It has finally dawned on me that pretty much everyone is making their configure scripts by taking one extensive, generic script and tweaking it for their own purposes.  If anyone knows what I am talking about, can you tell me the source for this generic configure script?  Thanks.

Comment: Many configure scripts are created by `autoconf`.  Be warned that many of the people using autoconf have no idea what they are doing and many configure scripts are atrocious.  (Which is not to imply that the configure scripts generated by knowledgeable users are not also atrocious!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).

I would imagine that the [Goat Book](http://sourceware.org/autobook/) offers a comprehensive treatment of it.

Do not taunt autoconf.